# Why does Rcpp corrupt xts object?

Tags: r, rcpp, xts

Say I have an xts object and return the index via an Rcpp function.  Touching the xts object in this way seems to corrupt the xts object.

It can be fixed by forcing a deep copy.

While i do have a work-around, i don't understand why the problem exists -- or why my hack is required?

Using the suggested code from dirk's [Rcpp Gallery](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/getting-attributes-for-xts-example/), the xts object is corrupted once touched.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
DatetimeVector xtsIndex(NumericMatrix X) {
    DatetimeVector v(NumericVector(X.attr("index")));
    return v;
}

require(xts)
xx <- xts(1:10, order.by = seq.Date(Sys.Date(), by = "day", length.out = 10))

xtsIndex(xx)

...

> print(xx)
Error in Ops.POSIXt(.index(x), 86400) : 
  '%/%' not defined for "POSIXt" objects
```

Tweaking the code to force a deep copy prevents the corruption.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
DatetimeVector xtsIndex_deep(NumericMatrix X) {
    DatetimeVector v = clone(NumericVector(X.attr("index")));
    return v;
}

> xtsIndex_deep(xx)
 [1] "2021-05-13 UTC" "2021-05-14 UTC" "2021-05-15 UTC" "2021-05-16 UTC" "2021-05-17 UTC"
 [6] "2021-05-18 UTC" "2021-05-19 UTC" "2021-05-20 UTC" "2021-05-21 UTC" "2021-05-22 UTC"
> xx
           [,1] [,2]
2021-05-13    1   10
2021-05-14    2    9
2021-05-15    3    8
2021-05-16    4    7
2021-05-17    5    6
2021-05-18    6    5
2021-05-19    7    4
2021-05-20    8    3
2021-05-21    9    2
2021-05-22   10    1
```

what's going on?

Comment: There is a lot going on here and you are playing a little fast and loose. `xx` is an `xts` object as created, it has a single (int !!) data vector but you are forcing it into `xtsIndex` as a `NumericMatrix` --> so "stuff happens".  I agree that the side effects are not desirable but you also have to be a litte more careful with types.

Comment: The function from the Rcpp Gallery article may have been written using the old Date(time) classes, I would have to check.  A simpler version is `cppFunction("SEXP xtsIndex(NumericMatrix X) { SEXP s = X.attr(\"index\");  return s; } ")` which should avoid extra casting and work with Date and Datetime index objects.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel i just tested your suggested fix and i get the same `'%/%' not defined for "POSIXt" objects` error. but thanks for your speedy attention.

Comment: I did the sequence of defining that function, then the same `xx <- xts(1:10, order.by = seq.Date(Sys.Date(), by = "day", length.out = 10))` followed by `xtsIndex(xx)` after which which `xx` still prints as an `xts` object.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel yep it works.  please post as an answer and i'll upvote.  i still don't understand exactly what went wrong though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot reproduce that with a simpler attribute extraction function all is well and xx is not altered:

```
> cppFunction("SEXP xtsIndex(NumericMatrix X) { SEXP s = X.attr(\"index\");  return s; } ") 
> xx <- xts(1:10, order.by = seq.Date(Sys.Date(), by = "day", length.out = 10))   
> head(xx)         
           [,1]    
2021-05-13    1    
2021-05-14    2    
2021-05-15    3    
2021-05-16    4    
2021-05-17    5    
2021-05-18    6    
>                  
> xtsIndex(xx)     
 [1] 1620864000 1620950400 1621036800 1621123200 1621209600 1621296000 
 [7] 1621382400 1621468800 1621555200 1621641600         
attr(,"tzone")                                           
[1] "UTC"                                                
attr(,"tclass")                                          
[1] "Date"                                               
>                                                        
> head(xx)                                               
           [,1]                                          
2021-05-13    1                                          
2021-05-14    2                                          
2021-05-15    3    
2021-05-16    4    
2021-05-17    5    
2021-05-18    6    
>
```

The function `xtsIndex` will create a copy on input (as our `xts` object contains an integer sequence as data the `NumericMatrix` will surely be a copied object, but it retains the `attribute` we can extract).

Note, however, how the `Date` sequence from `xx` is now displayed in units of a `POSIXct` or `Datetime`.  This looks like a possible error from a coercion which `xts` (or possibly `Rcpp` but I think it is `xts` here) may do here.  You are probably better off starting with a `POSIXct` time object even if it daily data.

Doing so also allow us to properly type the extractor function for `Datetime`:

```
> cppFunction("DatetimeVector xtsIndex(NumericMatrix X) { 
                   return DatetimeVector(wrap(X.attr(\"index\"))); } ")   
> xx <- xts(1:10, order.by = as.POSIXct(seq.Date(Sys.Date(), by = "day", length.out = 10))) 
> head(xx)   
                    [,1]    
2021-05-12 19:00:00    1    
2021-05-13 19:00:00    2    
2021-05-14 19:00:00    3    
2021-05-15 19:00:00    4    
2021-05-16 19:00:00    5    
2021-05-17 19:00:00    6    
> head(xtsIndex(xx))        
[1] "2021-05-12 19:00:00 CDT" "2021-05-13 19:00:00 CDT" "2021-05-14 19:00:00 CDT"  
[6] "2021-05-15 19:00:00 CDT" "2021-05-16 19:00:00 CDT" "2021-05-17 19:00:00 CDT" 
> head(xx)  
                    [,1]        
2021-05-12 19:00:00    1        
2021-05-13 19:00:00    2        
2021-05-14 19:00:00    3        
2021-05-15 19:00:00    4        
2021-05-16 19:00:00    5        
2021-05-17 19:00:00    6        
>
```

Comment: note that the 'fix' works due to the conversion of the index in `xx` to `POSIXct`.  If the `DateTimeVector` typed function @dirk suggests above is used on an `xx` that has a 'Date' index the original `xx` in the R session is corrupted.

Comment: You have to be more careful about crossing from Date to Datetime in compiled code. I strongly recommend you stick to POSIXct in the compiled code.

Comment: okay will do, thanks. I am very curious as to why this happens. if you could post a link that'd be helpful.

Comment: @ricardo: You do realize that Dates are type integer and not double?

Comment: @IRTFM .... wonderful suggestion! I had copied the code from the Rcpp-gallery and not thought carefully about it.  If i declare the extraction function as an `IntegerVector` the corruption doesn't occur. that still leaves the *why* question.  `idx_dd <- cppFunction("IntegerVector xtsIndex_dd(NumericMatrix X) { return IntegerVector(X.attr(\"index\")); } ") `

Comment: I also explained that to you earlier.  Date uses `int`, Datetime uses `numeric`, and `xts` is happier with the latter.  It simply depends on how you construct your `xts` objects and just about everybody recommends using numeric i.e. Dateime.  But you had a tendency to rush through this, overlook the fact and then mistakenly call this "corruption".  It isn't.  But C/C++ are typed and you can inadvertently force _copies_ into the other type.