# Iterate over R object using SEXP in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, xts

I'd like to subset an `xts` object in an `Rcpp` function and return the subset.

If the `xts` object has an index of class `Date` extracting the index via `Rcpp` corrupts the `xts` object -- see [dirk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67513371/why-does-rcpp-corrupt-xts-object?noredirect=1#comment119332533_67513371) to this question, where he demonstrates that getting a pointer to the `Date` indices from the `xts` (what i call the `SEXP` approach) doesn't lead to corruption.

Say that i have a pointer `s` to the `SEXP` in `Rcpp` -- how do i iterate over the underlying object using that SEXP? Can it be done?

I'd like to iterate over the underlying object, and return a subset of that object.

The below R code does what I require:

```
set.seed(1)
require(xts)
xx_date <- xts(round(runif(100, min = 0, max = 20), 0), 
  order.by = seq.Date(Sys.Date(), by = "day", length.out = 100))

subXts_r <- function(Xts) {
  i = 2
  while( as.numeric(Xts[i, ]) != as.numeric(Xts[i-1, ])) {
    if (i == nrow(Xts)) break else i = i+1
  }
  Xts[1:i,]
}

subXts_r(xx_date)
```

This `Rcpp` code also does what I want, but it uses a `clone` of the `index` (second line) to prevent corruption.  My idea is to *replace the second line* with `SEXP s = X.attr(\"index\")` -- but I don't know how to iterate over `s` once I have it.

```
cppFunction("NumericVector subXts_cpp(NumericMatrix X) {
            DatetimeVector v = clone(NumericVector(X.attr(\"index\"))); // need to clone else xx_date is corrupted
            double * p_dt = v.begin() +1;
            double * p_value = X.begin() +1;
            while( (*p_value != *(p_value -1)) & (p_value < X.end())) {
              p_value++;
              p_dt++;
            }

            Rcpp::NumericVector toDoubleValue(X.begin(), p_value);
            Rcpp::NumericVector toDoubleDate(v.begin(), p_dt);

            int rows = toDoubleValue.size(); // find length of xts object

            toDoubleDate.attr(\"tzone\")    = \"UTC\";         // the index has attributes
  CharacterVector t_class  = CharacterVector::create(\"POSIXct\", \"POSIXt\");
            toDoubleDate.attr(\"tclass\")   = t_class;

  // now modify dataVec to make into an xts
  toDoubleValue.attr(\"dim\")         = IntegerVector::create(rows,1);
  toDoubleValue.attr(\"index\")       = toDoubleDate;
  CharacterVector d_class  = CharacterVector::create(\"xts\", \"zoo\");
  toDoubleValue.attr(\"class\")       = d_class;
  toDoubleValue.attr(\".indexCLASS\") = t_class;
  toDoubleValue.attr(\"tclass\")      = t_class;
  toDoubleValue.attr(\".indexTZ\")    = \"UTC\";
  toDoubleValue.attr(\"tzone\")       = \"UTC\";
            return toDoubleValue;}")
```

Comment: SEXP objects already _are_ pointers as the letters expand to  "Pointer to SEX object".   And this question seems a little confused.  Did you look at my answer to your other question?

Comment: I confess I have no idea what you actually want to do, and little of what you wrote makes sense.  You don't need iterators (we have vectorized commands in Rcpp Sugar), I showed you in the other question that you do not need deep copies (unless I misunderstand something).  Maybe best to delete this question, think things over and maybe show with a simple _working_ R example what you want to do, and then whatever C++ code you have that tries to replicate it.  (Also note that xts operations are efficient, you will bit be faster just because you force them to be done in C++.)

Comment: I am always happy to help people -- I have answered apprently more than 3700 times on this site -- but you have to  help me help you.  If the question is unclear, convoluted, too long, ... or otherwise off-putting I may just move on, as to other help.  Make it _easy_ and _obvious_ what you want, did, and are struggling with and people may spend their spare time helping you for free.